# How to generate url preview for facebook links

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I wanted to know does facebook offer any API (for mobile App) so I can get metadata or anything so I can parse it & generate preview of the post from facebook url

Thanks

Comment: They offer the Embedded Posts plugin to embed posts on your site, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/embedded-posts/

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately I am building an app (so I can't use the embed post) which allows users to copy and paste the links and I want to generate UI preview of the link by displaying title, description and image if it has.

Comment: Are you talking about the Open Graph meta data Facebook extracts when _external_ links are shared in a post, or Facebook posts themselves?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v11.0/url can be queried for the OG data Facebook has extracted for externalURLs.

Comment: I want to generate ui preview of Facebook post (not other website), for example I want to get title, description & image from this url https://www.facebook.com/nytimes/posts/10152709822079999 and to generate ui preview inside my app when someone share facebook post

Comment: For that, you would need to get your app approved for the [Page Public Content Access](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/features-reference/page-public-content-access) feature first; but – _“Allowed Usage: Provide competitive benchmark analysis.”_ So it is rather unlikely that you will get it for such a purpose.